# Linking errors with MinGW and FLTK

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, build, linker, fltk

I know very little about C++, I'm used to Java where compiling is so simple! Anyways, I'm trying to use Eclipse Kepler to write a program that implements the FLTK graphics library. I think my compiler is MinGW. Here is what it prints out when I build the program:

http://hastebin.com/jefepobula.vbs

Here is the code (it is the example code from FLTK's documentation):

http://hastebin.com/fujafuyiqa.coffee

I really appreciate any help with this. It's been very frustrating for me and my friend. Like I said, C++ is pretty overwhelming for me as far as the steps it takes just to run your code.

Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Linker reports missing symbols. Looks like it can't find COMCTRL32 and UUID libraries.